# vimscript: strange behavior of search() with flags 'be'?

Tags: vimscript, search, functions

vim-help `:h search()` says it start search at column 0 of cursor position.

> Search for regexp pattern {pattern}.  The search starts at the cursor
>   position (you can use |cursor()| to set it).
>   ....
>
> 'b'   search Backward instead of forward
>   'e'   move to the End of the match
>   'z'   start searching at the cursor column instead of zero
>
> .... When the 'z' flag is not given, searching always starts in column
>   zero and then matches before the cursor are skipped. When the 'c' flag
>   is present in 'cpo' the next search starts after the match.  Without
>   the 'c' flag the next search starts one column further.

Thus, when below script being sourced,

```
func! GoParagraphStart(flags) range abort
    echo search('^',a:flags)
endfunc

nnoremap <silent> { :call GoParagraphStart('be')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> } :call GoParagraphStart('e')<CR>
```

I suppose, be the cursor at the first column or not, pressing <kbd>{</kbd> will always move cursor to previous line. But the result is

- go previous line if cursor at first column
- go first column of current line if not at first column.

Which make me puzzled.

**Question:** Is the behavior wrong, or I mis-interpreted the meaning of the help file?

version:  vim 8.0 with patch 1-1216 on Cygwin64

**== motivation & the true problem ==**
previous function definition is for illustrative purpose, original one is

```
func! GoParagraphStart(flags) range abort
    if v:count < 2
        call search('\(\_^\s*\_$\n\_^.\)', a:flags)
    else
        let cnt = 0
        while cnt < v:count
            call search('\(\_^\s*\_$\n\_^.\)', a:flags) 
            let cnt += 1
        endwhile
    endif
endfunc
```

**The behavior I needed is**, when cursor at first line or a paragraph, pressing <kbd>{</kbd> will go previous paragraph's first line, no matter cursor at column zero or not. However, currently not working if cursor not at column zero.

**== P.S. ==**

Answer not answering the question, but instead do fix and achieve the intended behavior is well-appreciated too.

**== Edit ==**

As @statox stated, the behavior is indeed as documented, the departure is because, depends on `found-pos == line('.'), col('.')`, the result will be rejected if true, else accept. unless flag `c` is specified.

Thus, the fix is easy, add `call cursor('.',1)` or `norm! 0` before do search.

(side notes. concerning `norm! k$`, it fixs backward search, but break forward search.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why does the search move the cursor to the previous line if you are on the first column?

If you are on the first `a` of the following line:

```
abcabc
```

Using `call search('a')` will move the cursor to the 4th letter of the line. It is because `search()` by default doesn't accept a match at the cursor position (you can use the flag `c` to change that). Thus it is the same when you search backward: the beginning of the line at the current position is not accepted by search. The behavior you are observing is the one which is documented.

#### How to solve that?

If you want to always go to the previous line you should be able to use `norm! k$` before you use `search()` this way you will always be on the end of the previous line and you should get the behavior `go first column of current line if not at first column.` each time.

Comment: So, the reason is:  the search is indeed always start at `line('.') 1`, but since the found position is also `line('.') 1`, thus depending `col('.') eq `1` or not, the result will be rejected/accepted, unless overridden by flag 'c'?

Comment: And the fix is quite easy, just move cursor to column 1 before search, `call cursor('.',1)`. (just verified that) or as suggested, use `norm! k$`.

Comment: @qeatzy I'm not sure I fully understand your first comment but I think you got it right: if you are on the first column, this first column itself is ignored. About the fix: yes moving to the first column with `cursor()` or `norm! 0` should work just like `norm! k$`